How to add 'Accept' header to ClientWebSocket
I am working on a C# app that need to connect to WebSocket server.
WebSocket-Server app's vendor (the client that app is creating for) enforces to use "Accept": "application/json" header. Without this i got "Bad Request (400)" response.
I tried it with postman, works good.
But when i try to add this accept header in C# app, I got exception:

The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name

My code:
            var WS = new ClientWebSocket();
            var CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            WS.Options.SetRequestHeader("jwt-token", "token"); // Token provided by vendor
            WS.Options.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            try
            {
                await WS.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://sever-url"), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(ReceiveLoop, CTS.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

Any idea how can i add this header when connecting?

Looks like it's a longstanding issue with the ClientWebSocket implementation where they've borrowed some, but not enough, of the other web request functionality. Perhaps you can hook in at the HttpMessageInvoker / HttpMessageHandler level (the former is a parameter in an overload of ConnectAsync) to alter the request as it travels the pipeline.
